# Transforming Complex Flat File using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a flat file which has format something like below,

```
Country{Year{Working_Days_Month1{Working_Days_Month2...{Working_Days_Month12
IND{2019{111110011111001111100111110011{111110011111001111100111110011....{111110011111001111100111110011
```

I need to transform the above data to a table or json as below with following columns,

Column 1 - Country

Column 2 - Year

Column 3 - Month{1-12)

Column 4 - Days (1-31)

Column 5 - Working Days of Particular Month ( 1 or 0 based on number of days present in flat file)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) from pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file", sep="{")
```

You can use `names` keyword argument in `read_csv` to give the column names as well.